# Basic pygame program template

Tags: python, template, pygame

I have a basic pygame program that I use at the start of every project that involves pygame. The idea is every time I start a project that involves pygame I can copy and past and I can immediately start on my project without changing anything. The reason I am posting this is because of another question I posted. The answering user told me to shift some lines of my program to `if __name__ == "__main__":` that were part of this basic pygame program. I am wondering what else I could do to improve this code.

```
import pygame

title = "Game"
size = (1000, 600)

def handle_events():
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return 1

    # keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    return 0

def draw():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # screen.blit()

def game_logic():
    pass

def run_game():
    while 1:
        game_logic()

        if handle_events():
            break

        draw()

        pygame.display.update(window_rect)

        clock.tick(30)

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    window_rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), size)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.display.set_caption(title)
    pygame.event.set_allowed([pygame.KEYDOWN, pygame.QUIT])
    run_game()
```

Comment: You could use `True` instead of `1` both in `while 1` line and in `return 1` statement. `1` works fine in python, but I think it fits more with boolean. There is not much code to review

Comment: what about pep8?, naming variables?

Comment: That is small loop, but if it would be bigger, using `e` as name is bad habit :) I would use maybe `ev` for event or `curr_event` to indicate in that iteration, but that is very subjective, just use name that will make you sure in future what that variable is :D

Comment: ok, i sometimes have to remind myself that `e` means event

Answer (score 2):

I have put together bits and pieces of advice from some comments and an answer to end up with this:

```
import pygame

TITLE = "Game"
SIZE = (1000, 600)


def handle_events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return False

    # keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    return True


def draw():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # screen.blit()


def game_logic():
    pass


def run_game():
    while handle_events():
        game_logic()

        draw()

        pygame.display.update(window_rect)

        clock.tick(30)

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
    window_rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), SIZE)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
    pygame.event.set_allowed([pygame.KEYDOWN, pygame.QUIT])
    run_game()
```

- Changed `e` variable to `event` for clarity.
- Changed `1` to `True` for clarity.
- Changed constants to uppercase.
- Put the `handle_events()` in the while loop condition, where it always should have been!

Feel free to comment below more improvements.

Answer (score 1):

**Name constants in uppercase**. This is a common and useful naming convention.

**Don't use one/zero if you mean true/false**. Like the previous comment, this
is focused on enhancing the code's readability and clarity of intent.

**Put all code in functions**. Code in functions can be tested, experimented
with, and reorganized much more easily than code floating around at the top
level. Floating code introduces the temptation to rely on global variables,
which can create substantial headaches even at moderate program sizes. Putting
everything in functions forces you to think clearly about how the behavior and
data flow is organized. It's a time-tested practice worth embracing.

**Organize the functions to help readability**. People read English top
to bottom. Arrange the functions in that order.

**Caveat**. I have no significant `pygame` experience so I cannot offer advice on those details.

```
import pygame
import sys

TITLE = 'Game'
SIZE = (1000, 600)

def main(args):
    pygame.init()
    ...
    run_game(screen, window_rect, clock)

def run_game(screen, window_rect, clock):
    while True:
        game_logic()
        if handle_events():
            break
        draw(screen)
        ...
    ...

def game_logic():
    ...

def handle_events():
    for ...
        if ...
            return True
    return False

def draw(screen):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```